# Remove sublist from list

Tags: python, list

I want to do the following in Python:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7]
C = A - [3, 4]  # Should be [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7]
C = A - [4, 3]  # Should not be removing anything, because sequence 4, 3 is not found
```

So, I simply want to remove the first appearance of a sublist (as a sequence) from another list. How can I do that?

**Edit:** I am talking about lists, not sets. Which implies that ordering (sequence) of items matter (**both** in A and B), as well as duplicates.

Comment: that doesnt even makes sense, i think you mean `A - B`

Comment: does order matter? what is the output if `A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 8, 5, 4]`?

Comment: so just removed all when multiple matches? or only first match?

Comment: @pault Order and duplicates do matter.

Comment: You should subclass `list` and define its `__sub__` method. All 3 answers (at current point) work for the example you gave, but none does for the general case.

Comment: do you need to remove multiple sublist at the same time?

Comment: I reopened this question. Note that I still think it is worded extremely vague and invites misunderstandings, but it is not the "subtract two lists" duplicate. Edit: The latest edit made it more understandable.

Comment: @Sphinx Only the first match. I updated my question. Apparently a lot of things were not clear.

Answer (score 29):

Use sets:

```
C = list(set(A) - set(B))
```

In case you want to mantain duplicates and/or oder:

```
filter_set = set(B)
C = [x for x in A if x not in filter_set]
```

Comment: This is not going to maintain duplicates... Right?

Comment: Look at my updated question. I am talking about lists, not sets. Order also matters.

Comment: This will not maintain the original order of the elements. Do something like `[i for i in A if i not in B]`

Comment: @Feng, care to read the second part of the answer...

Comment: @Netwave My solution does not need to make it a set.

Comment: @Feng and it would be much slower for larger lists.

Comment: None of these answers work for B= [4, 3], which as the OP said, should not remove anything. Thanks for the answers though, as they would help those seeking for removing values from lists in a simple and straightforward manner.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove exact sequences, here is one way:

Find the bad indices by checking to see if the sublist matches the desired sequence:

```
bad_ind = [range(i,i+len(B)) for i,x in enumerate(A) if A[i:i+len(B)] == B]
print(bad_ind)
#[[2, 3]]
```

Since this returns a list of lists, flatten it and turn it into a set:

```
bad_ind_set = set([item for sublist in bad_ind for item in sublist])
print(bad_ind_set)
#set([2, 3])
```

Now use this set to filter your original list, by index:

```
C = [x for i,x in enumerate(A) if i not in bad_ind_set]
print(C)
#[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7]
```

The above `bad_ind_set` will remove all matches of the sequence. If you only want to remove the first match, it's even simpler. You just need the first element of `bad_ind` (no need to flatten the list):

```
bad_ind_set = set(bad_ind[0])
```

---

**Update**: Here is a way to find and remove the first matching sub-sequence using a short circuiting `for` loop. This will be faster because it will break out once the first match is found.

```
start_ind = None
for i in range(len(A)):
    if A[i:i+len(B)] == B:
        start_ind = i
        break

C = [x for i, x in enumerate(A) 
     if start_ind is None or not(start_ind <= i < (start_ind + len(B)))]
print(C)
#[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7]
```

Comment: I am thinking about this question is similar with substring query, why not consider one solution like KMP etc

Answer (score 2):

I considered this question was like one substring search, so **KMP**, **BM** etc [sub-string search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) could be applied at here. Even you'd like support multiple patterns, there are some multiple pattern algorithms like **[Aho-Corasick](https://doc.rust-lang.org/regex/aho_corasick/index.html)**, **[Wu-Manber](https://github.com/jneem/wu-manber)** etc.

Below is [KMP algorithm implemented by Python](https://gist.github.com/m00nlight/daa6786cc503fde12a77) which is from GitHub Gist.
**PS: the author is not me. I just want to share my idea.**

```
class KMP:
    def partial(self, pattern):
        """ Calculate partial match table: String -> [Int]"""
        ret = [0]

        for i in range(1, len(pattern)):
            j = ret[i - 1]
            while j > 0 and pattern[j] != pattern[i]:
                j = ret[j - 1]
            ret.append(j + 1 if pattern[j] == pattern[i] else j)
        return ret

    def search(self, T, P):
        """
        KMP search main algorithm: String -> String -> [Int]
        Return all the matching position of pattern string P in S
        """
        partial, ret, j = self.partial(P), [], 0

        for i in range(len(T)):
            while j > 0 and T[i] != P[j]:
                j = partial[j - 1]
            if T[i] == P[j]: j += 1
            if j == len(P):
                ret.append(i - (j - 1))
                j = 0

        return ret
```

**Then use it to calcuate out the matched position, finally remove the match:**

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 3, 4]
B = [3, 4]
result = KMP().search(A, B)
print(result)
#assuming at least one match is found
print(A[:result[0]:] + A[result[0]+len(B):])
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 9]
[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 3, 4]
[Finished in 0.201s]
```

**PS**: You can try other algorithms also. And @Pault 's answers is good enough unless you care about the performance a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7]
B = [3,4]
C = [4,3]
list(np.setdiff1d(A,B, assume_unique=True))
output: [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7]
list(np.setdiff1d(A,C, assume_unique=True))
output: [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

```
# Returns that starting and ending point (index) of the sublist, if it exists, otherwise 'None'.

def findSublist(subList, inList):
    subListLength = len(subList)
    for i in range(len(inList)-subListLength):
        if subList == inList[i:i+subListLength]:
            return (i, i+subListLength)
    return None


# Removes the sublist, if it exists and returns a new list, otherwise returns the old list.

def removeSublistFromList(subList, inList):
    indices = findSublist(subList, inList)
    if not indices is None:
        return inList[0:indices[0]] + inList[indices[1]:]
    else:
        return inList


A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7]

s1 = [3,4]
B = removeSublistFromList(s1, A)
print(B)

s2 = [4,3]
C = removeSublistFromList(s2, A)
print(C)
```

Comment: Thanks, you just wrote and `s1` when you wanted to say `C = removeSublistFromList(s2, A)`, at the end.